# Why did Melina ask this question?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow* (2021), Melina snatches photo album from Natasha, who is looking through it:

> Natasha: Why you doing this?
>
> Melina: **Why does a mouse born in a cage run on that little wheel?**
> Do you know I was cycled through the Red Room four times before
> you were even born? Those walls are all I know.

Why did Melina ask this question?

Comment: Why not consider also joining our sister-site [ell.se] for further language-learning related resources.

Comment: According to this meta post, this type of question is on topic for this site - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13923/153074

Comment: I'm curious, why do you feel the need to pont that out? @A.Steer

Comment: @JiminyCricket. On past experience if someone doesn't point out this kind of question is on topic it attracts close votes for being off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an use of language question than sci-fi specific.

This is a rhetorical question.

> noun.
> a question asked in order to create a dramatic effect or to make a point rather than to get an answer.

The intent is to point out that Natasha's question has an obvious answer. Melina does this because it is all she knows.